# Can't get Freeglut to work with Haskell on Windows

Tags: windows, haskell, opengl, freeglut

Here is my source code I'm trying to get to work:

In Main.hs:

```
import Graphics.Rendering.OpenGL
import Graphics.UI.GLUT
import Bindings
import Data.IORef
main = do
    (progname,_) <- getArgsAndInitialize
    createWindow "Hello World"
    reshapeCallback $= Just reshape
    keyboardMouseCallback $= Just keyboardMouse
    angle <- newIORef 0.0
    displayCallback $= display
    idleCallback $= Just idle
    mouseWheelCallback $= Just mouseWheel
    mainLoop
```

In Bindings.hs:

```
module Bindings where
import Graphics.Rendering.OpenGL
import Graphics.UI.GLUT

display :: IO ()
display = return ()

overlayDisplay :: IO ()
overlayDisplay = return ()

visibility :: Visibility -> IO ()
visibility v = return ()

reshape :: Size -> IO ()
reshape s@(Size w h) = do 
    viewport $= (Position 0 0, s)

close :: IO ()
close = return ()

keyboardMouse :: Key -> KeyState -> Modifiers -> Position -> IO ()
keyboardMouse key state modifiers position = return ()

mouseWheel :: WheelNumber -> WheelDirection -> Position -> IO ()
mouseWheel wn wd p = return ()

idle :: IO ()
idle = return ()
```

It works if I use normal glut32.dll and none of the freeglut extensions in my code, but I want to use the freeglut extensions.

When I use freeglut.dll, rename it to glut32.dll, and put it in the same folder as my .exe, it gives me the error:

```
main: user error (unknown GLUT entry glutInit)
```

When I use the normal glut32.dll in the same way I get the error:

```
main: user error (unknown GLUT entry glutMouseWheelFunc)
```

Comment: If you've solved your problem, please consider closing the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use freeglut .lib/.dll from Mingw or compile it yourself.

Answer (score 9):

1. download glut from http://www.transmissionzero.co.uk/software/freeglut-devel/. Be sure to download the MinGW version.
2. copy the file `freeglut-MinGW-3.0.0-1.mp.zip\freeglut\bin\x64\freeglut.dll` to `C:\Windows\System32`. Make sure you get the 64 bit version from the `x64` folder.
3. rename it as `glut32.dll`

I just solved this problem and hope this could help others.

Comment: Thanks. Nice hack.