# GLUT Error in Haskell Program

Tags: haskell, opengl, glut, freeglut

I'm using OpenGL with Haskell. I tried a sample program, it compiled successfully using ghc Compiler but when I run it, I get this error

user error (unknown GLUT entry glutInit)

I searched about this but most of the answers were related to this problem occurring is mac OS X and Windows. But I am getting this error on Ubuntu 15.

[This Question was Previously asked but is related to windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8956387/7826296)

Below is the Sample Program that I used.

```
import Graphics.Rendering.OpenGL
import Graphics.UI.GLUT

main :: IO ()
main = do
    (_progName, _args) <- getArgsAndInitialize
    _window <- createWindow "Hello World"
    displayCallback $= display
    mainLoop

display :: IO ()
display = do
    clear [ ColorBuffer ]
```

Comment: Could you provide your code and examples, that would help I would imagine.

Comment: try `sudo apt-get install freeglut3`

Comment: @user2297560 Thank you for sharing this here, it solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your system is missing the required shared library. On Ubuntu (and similar systems), you can install it with this simple command in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install freeglut3
```