# Exception: user error (unknown GLUT entry glutInit) on ubuntu

Tags: haskell, gloss

i keep getting this error when trying to use gloss on ubuntu. this is my code.

```
import Graphics.Gloss

main :: IO ()
main = display window background drawing
    where
      window = InWindow "Nice Window" (200, 200) (0, 0) 
      background = white 
      drawing = Circle 80
```

Can you guys help me??

Comment: what does `ldd ./your_executable` says? does it find libglut?

Comment: If this problem persists you could try to avoid glut by installing gloss via `cabal install gloss -fglfw` (i.e. use the glfw flag).

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was missing `freeglut` package.

```
$ cd /usr/lib; find | grep glut
```

It should find something like this:

```
./libglut.so
./libglut.so.3
./libglut.so.3.11.0
```

If you lack similar files chances are you have the same problem as I did.
Just install `freeglut` package.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that your system is missing the required shared library. On Ubuntu (and similar systems), you can install it with this simple command in a terminal:
>
> `sudo apt-get install freeglut3`

from
[GLUT Error in Haskell Program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43253228/glut-error-in-haskell-program)